# xsl key not passing through variables

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I've got the following xml:

```
<section>
  <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.2.4" />
  <text>
    <list listType="ordered">
      <item>9/18/2013 - Weight - 125 lbs</item>
      <item>9/18/2013 - Blood Pressure - 120/80 mm Hg</item>
      <item>9/18/2013 - BMI - 19 98</item>
    </list>
  </text>
</section>
```

I need to have the html output appear as the following:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>9/18/2013</td>
    <td>Blood Pressure - 120/80</td>
    <td>Weight - 125lbs</td>
    <td>BMI - 19</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have the following key set up in my xsl file:

```
<xsl:key name="vs_times" match="//hl7:section[hl7:templateId/@root='2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.2.4']/hl7:text/hl7:list/hl7:item" use="substring-before(., ' - ')"/>
```

This is to get the date. In my xml, there COULD be more than one set of dates (but at most two) and the second date option would be another row in the table example above.

This is my xsl template information to output:

```
<xsl:template match="hl7:section[hl7:templateId/@root='2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.2.4']">
  <div style="padding: 5px; border-top: 1px solid #000000;">
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" width="100%">
      <xsl:for-each select="hl7:text/hl7:list/hl7:item[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('vs_times', substring-before(., ' - ')))]">
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 76px;">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., ' - ')" />
          </td>
          <xsl:variable name="values" select="key('vs_times', substring-after(., ' - '))"/>
          <td style="width: 180px; padding-left: 3px;">
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="substring-before($values, ' - ') = 'Blood Pressure'">
                <span style="font-weight: bold;">Blood Pressure: </span>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($values, ' - ')"/>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                &#xa0;
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

(this is just a snippet. if I can get the one table cell to show up for the blood pressure, then I can duplicate that for the other list items). The issue I'm having is that the date is showing up without issue. However, the next table cell is not showing up. I don't know if I'm referencing my key wrong or if I'm referencing the value to show wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have `substring-after` where you should have `substring-before`:

```
<xsl:variable name="values" select="key('vs_times', substring-after(., ' - '))"/>
```

should be:

```
<xsl:variable name="values" select="key('vs_times', substring-before(., ' - '))"/>
```

And this should have `substring-after`:

```
<xsl:when test="substring-before($values, ' - ') = 'Blood Pressure'">
```

Also, you'll need to iterate through the items in `$values` (preferably with templates rather than `for-each`), but it seems like you might already know that. Something like this:

```
  <xsl:template match="hl7:section
                         [hl7:templateId/@root='2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.2.4']">
    <div style="padding: 5px; border-top: 1px solid #000000;">
      <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" width="100%">
        <xsl:apply-templates
          select="hl7:text/hl7:list/hl7:item
                       [generate-id(.)=
                        generate-id(key('vs_times', 
                                        substring-before(., ' - ')))]" 
          mode="group" />
      </table>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="hl7:item" mode="group">
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 76px;">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., ' - ')" />
      </td>
      <xsl:variable name="values" select="key('vs_times', 
                                              substring-before(., ' - '))"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$values" />
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="hl7:item">
    <td style="width: 180px; padding-left: 3px;">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="content" />
    </td>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="hl7:item[contains(., 'Blood Pressure')]" mode="content">
    <span style="font-weight: bold;">Blood Pressure: </span>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., 'Blood Pressure - ')"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="hl7:item" mode="content">
    &#xa0;
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: The only problem with the second template is that the formatting needs to be different potentially for each item in the list. I had looked into that but it would be more choose/when in the second template and was just simpler for me to do it in the first one. I can make an attempt with this though.

Comment: @jjasper0729 There is almost never a good reason to use a `choose/when` instead of templates, especially in a situation like this. If you'd like to open up a separate question regarding how to get the formatting right in an elegant manner, I'd be more than happy to help out.

Comment: I think I might open up a second one. This works great but I need the items in a specific order that could be different from the order they are iterated through (for instance, the xml has weight, then blood pressure, then bmi, but the output should be bp, weight, bmi). In addition if there isn't one of those, there needs to be a blank space accounting for it in the output

Comment: I started a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19186883/specific-order-for-xsl-template-output. Thanks for the help with this. I'm still learning xpath/xsl coming from .NET so the templates vs linear methods is something i'm trying to contend with in my mind.