# Specific order for XSL Template output

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

I've got the following xml file:

```
<section>
  <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.2.4" />
  <text>
    <list listType="ordered">
      <item>9/18/2013 - Weight - 125 lbs</item>
      <item>9/18/2013 - Blood Pressure - 120/80 mm Hg</item>
      <item>9/18/2013 - BMI - 19 98</item>
      <item>9/11/2013 - Weight - 125 lbs</item>
      <item>9/11/2013 - Blood Pressure - 120/80 mm Hg</item>
      <item>9/11/2013 - BMI - 19 98</item>
      <item>9/11/2013 - Pulse - 32</item>
    </list>
  </text>
</section>
```

I have the following xsl template information:

```
<xsl:key name="vs_times" match="//hl7:section[hl7:templateId/@root='2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.2.4']/hl7:text/hl7:list/hl7:item" use="substring-before(., ' - ')"/>

    <xsl:template match="hl7:section[hl7:templateId/@root='2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.2.4']">
    <div style="padding: 5px; border-top: 1px solid #000000;">
        <span style="font-weight: bold;">Vital Signs: </span>
        <br/>
        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" width="100%">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="hl7:text/hl7:list/hl7:item[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('vs_times', substring-before(., ' - ')))]" mode="group" />
        </table>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="hl7:item" mode="group">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 76px;">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., ' - ')" />
        </td>
        <xsl:variable name="values" select="key('vs_times', substring-before(., ' - '))"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$values" />
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="hl7:item">
    <td style="width: 180px; padding-left: 3px;">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="content" />
    </td>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="hl7:item[contains(., 'Blood Pressure')]" mode="content">
    <span style="font-weight: bold;">Blood Pressure: </span>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(., 'Blood Pressure - '), ' ')"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="hl7:item[contains(., 'Pulse')]" mode="content">
    <span style="font-weight: bold;">Pulse: </span>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(., 'Pulse - '), ' ')"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="hl7:item[contains(., 'Weight')]" mode="content">
    <span style="font-weight: bold;">Weight: </span>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., 'Weight - ')"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="hl7:item[contains(., 'BMI')]" mode="content">
    <span style="font-weight: bold;">BMI: </span>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(., 'BMI - '), ' ')"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="hl7:item" mode="content">
    &#xa0;
</xsl:template>
```

This outputs the information but I need the output to be in a different order (potentially) than the items being iterated through. I need them to be the same order all the time:

- Blood Pressure
- Pulse
- Weight
- BMI

As of now, it's just looping through each item and outputting them as it comes to them.

Also, if there isn't one of the four items (as there is no pulse item in the first set of dates in the example) there needs to be a blank space. Finally, the second row needs to be an alternate color than the first row.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [xsl key not passing through variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19184248/xsl-key-not-passing-through-variables)

Comment: @Viji not a duplicate.. an extension... the other question does work and was answered, but now I need further assistance to get the items to display in a specific order (as opposed to just getting them to display at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit tricky, but please give this a try. It turns out that this did seem like a good time to use `choose/when` but not in the manner you were planning to:

```
  <xsl:key name="vs_times" 
           match="hl7:section
                      [hl7:templateId/@root='2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.2.4']
                      /hl7:text/hl7:list/hl7:item" use="substring-before(., ' - ')"/>

  <xsl:template match="hl7:section
                         [hl7:templateId/@root='2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.2.4']">
    <div style="padding: 5px; border-top: 1px solid #000000;">
      <span style="font-weight: bold;">Vital Signs: </span>
      <br/>
      <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" width="100%">
        <xsl:apply-templates
          select="hl7:text/hl7:list/hl7:item
                     [generate-id(.)=
                      generate-id(key('vs_times', 
                                  substring-before(., ' - ')))]"
          mode="group" />
      </table>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="hl7:item" mode="group">
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 76px;">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., ' - ')" />
      </td>
      <xsl:variable name="values"
                    select="key('vs_times', substring-before(., ' - '))"/>

      <xsl:call-template name="row">
        <xsl:with-param name="type" select="'Blood Pressure'" />
        <xsl:with-param name="values" select="$values" />
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:call-template name="row">
        <xsl:with-param name="type" select="'Pulse'" />
        <xsl:with-param name="values" select="$values" />
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:call-template name="row">
        <xsl:with-param name="type" select="'Weight'" />
        <xsl:with-param name="values" select="$values" />
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:call-template name="row">
        <xsl:with-param name="type" select="'BMI'" />
        <xsl:with-param name="values" select="$values" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="row">
    <xsl:param name="type" />
    <xsl:param name="values" select="/.." />

    <xsl:variable name="foundValue" select="$values[contains(., $type)]" />

    <td style="width: 180px; padding-left: 3px;">
      <xsl:if test="$type = 'Pulse' or $type = 'BMI'">
        <xsl:attribute name="class">alternate</xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>

      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$foundValue">
          <span style="font-weight: bold;">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat($type, ': ')" />
          </span>
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($foundValue, concat($type, ' - '))"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:text>&#xa0;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Put the information in but now i'm getting nothing returned when I was before (just in the wrong order)

Comment: @jjasper0729 Hm. It seems to work ok for me. Perhaps your XSLT processor doesn't submit using the `document()` function the way I am using it above. What processor are you using?

Comment: This is xslt 1.0 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xmlns:hl7="urn:hl7-org:v3" 
 xmlns:cda="urn:hl7-org:v3" 
 xmlns:sdtc="urn:hl7-org:sdtc"
 >

Comment: is the document() function an xslt 2.0 feature?

Comment: @jjasper0729 No, it's 1.0, but it's not fully supported by certain XSLT processors. What are you using to execute the XSLT? Are you having a browser execute it?

Comment: yes, this is being displayed in a web browser as a subsection of a larger asp.net page (loaded into an asp.net asp:xml control)

Comment: I see, well I've modified my answer to use an approach that's somewhat less elegant, but confined to more orthodox features.

Comment: Awesome. It works. Although I do see your point about being less elegant. It would be much nicer to just iterate through. I am also going to have to put a choose/when set in because depending on the type, the value may have all text after the ' - ' or it may not. But this gives me the order that I'm looking for. Thanks for the assistance

Comment: Glad to help. And as one last comment, I suggest using CSS classes in your markup rather than inline styles. It will reduce a lot of the duplication in the output and make your page easier to maintain.

Comment: I most likely will go back through after I have the page output the way it's supposed to and pull the inline styles into a style block (I have one in place and waiting already)